# boostrap - Equals column Heights && Equal rows Height inside nested column

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

Good morning,

I did not figure out how to do trick this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ozC.png). Maybe somebody can helps ?

I have tryed to do so with thoses tricks but it did not works

```
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div className='col-md-2'>
        height = 3*y
      </div>
      <div className='col-md-10 '>
        <div>
          A  - height = y
        </div>
        <div>
          B - height = y
        </div>
        <div>
          C - height = y
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

.css

```
    .row-eq-height {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
    }
```

thank you for your help !!!!

Comment: You need to also post your css.

Comment: you are right 

here it is
         .row-eq-height {
           display: -webkit-box;
           display: -webkit-flex;
           display: -ms-flexbox;
           display: flex;
         }

Comment: i tried your code its working perfectly , what's your problem

Comment: indeed but it is a mirage 
this is more visible with the code i just posted below

Answer (score -1):

answer

.css

```
li3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33333%;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

.js

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div className='col-md-2'>
    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>

    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>

    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>
    height = 3*y<br/>
  </div>
  <div className='col-md-10 '>
    <li3>
      A  - height = y
    </li3>
    <li3>
      B - height = y
    </li3>
    <li3>
      C - height = y
    </li3>
  </div>
</div>
```